# Using VBA and MS Outlook, how can I detect when an existing meeting date and time changes?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using VBA to pull meeting objects from an Outlook calendar into a MS Access table. I have discovered that when an existing meeting date/time is changed, the EntryID also changes (EntryID is the unique identifier for all Outlook objects).

Not sure why MS chose to do this - it would make more sense to leave the EntryID alone and only update the properties/metadata of the meeting itself, since the EntryID is the equivalent of a database primary key or index value. But... here we are.

Does anyone know how to detect that an existing meeting has changed? I could check if the attendees and subject are the same and only the date/time is different, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way.

I was going to simply loop through meeting objects in the calendar and see if a record with the matching EntryID already exists in the table, but... MS decided to change the EntryID when the meeting details change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntryID is changed for an appointment only if the current user is an attendee and a meeting update is received from the organizer - Outlook recreates the appointment, but its appointment id (`Appointment.GlobalAppointmentID`) does not change.

If the appointment cannot be opened by its entry id, you can search the folder for a matching appointment based on the appointment id. Keep in mind that looping through all items in a folder (which can contain thousands of items) can be very slow, but OOM does not allow to search on binary properties in `Items.Find/FindNext` and `Items.Restrict`. You can switch to Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) - it's version of [RDOFolder](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm).[Items](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`Find` allows a query against a binary property, e.g. `"GlobalAppointmentID = '040000008200E00074C5B7101A...' "`

Comment: That is exactly what I needed - many thanks!! I can compare the GlobalAppointmentID as I import meetings and whenever I find a match, I check the start time of the meeting to see if it has changed from what is in the Access table.

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!